# how to insert tab in sed command?

Tags: sed, yaml, yq

I have a text file in which there's a YAML formatted code. Here's the code:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - release/*
      - rapid/*
      - Sprint/*
      - Unity/*
```

Now, I have a bash script through which I want to add a string after this string; "              - develop". Here's the point I want to maintain the spacing format.
Here;s my bash file code.

```
 $target_string= "      - develop"
 $replacment_string="      - TerraformTest/*"
 sed -i "/$target_string/a$replacment_string" test.txt
```

But the result I got it this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
- TerraformTest/*
      - release/*
      - rapid/*
      - Sprint/*
      - Unity/*
```

Is there any way, I can put tab in sed command to obtain the output like this:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - TerraformTest/*
      - release/*
      - rapid/*
      - Sprint/*
      - Unity/*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match match and grab space of search string in a capture group and use it in replacement:

```bash
sed -E 's~^([[:blank:]]*)- develop~&\n\1- TerraformTest/*~' file

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - TerraformTest/*
      - release/*
      - rapid/*
      - Sprint/*
      - Unity/*
```

Or using variables:

```bash
target_string='- develop'
replacment_string='- TerraformTest/*'

sed -E "s~^([[:blank:]]*)$target_string~&\n\1$replacment_string~" file

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - TerraformTest/*
      - release/*
      - rapid/*
      - Sprint/*
      - Unity/*
```

**Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `([[:blank:]]*)`: Match 0 or more whitespaces in capture group #1
- `$target_string`: Match string contained in `$target_string`

**Replacement:**

- `&`: Place whole match back
- `\n`: Place a line break
- `\1`: Place spaces string on next line
- `$replacment_string`: Place new replacement value

TO save changes inline use:

```bash
sed -i.bak -E "s~^([[:blank:]]*)$target_string~&\n\1$replacment_string~" file
```

Comment: But, I want to add the value in file... Sed -E only output it.

Comment: How to do it using sed -i

Comment: @Muhammad_Bilal just add the flag : `sed -i  -E ....` or use a redirection

Comment: The `N` command isn't needed and will fail if the `- develop` line occurs in the last line of the file. `/^([[:blank:]]*)- develop/s~~&\n\1- TerraformTest/*~` will suffice.

Comment: Thanks so much @M.NejatAydin, you are absolutely right. I have edited.

Comment: Or even `s~^([[:blank:]]*)- develop~&\n\1- TerraformTest/*~`

Answer (score 2):

You could use a YAML-aware tool such as [yq](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/). This command inserts `TerraformTest/*` as the second element in the array at `.trigger.branches.include`:

```bash
yq '
    .trigger.branches.include |=
        ([.[0], "TerraformTest/*", del(.[0])] | flatten)
' infile.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v RS= '
match($0,/^trigger:\n[[:space:]]+branches:\n[[:space:]]+include:\n[[:space:]]+- develop/){
  print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)"\n      - TerraformTest/*" substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Can you explain how `substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)` and `substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)` is working in your code?

Comment: @HatLess, your welcome, already ++ to your solution. Yes it's sub string for matched regex(1st one) and other one is for values after matching regex to cover all in all line value actually, cheers.

Comment: Ahhh. I see it now. Thanks for the explanation. I will play about with it to get a better grasp. Awesome solution!

Answer (score 1):

It is best practice to use a YAML aware tool such as yq, Perl, Python, etc.

Here is a Ruby:

```
ruby -r yaml -e 'y=YAML.load($<.read)
begin
    a=y["trigger"]["branches"]["include"]
    a.insert(a.find_index("develop")+1,"TerraformTest/*")
    puts YAML.dump(y)
rescue 
    puts "Not Found"
end
' file
```

Prints:

```
---
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - develop
    - TerraformTest/*
    - release/*
    - rapid/*
    - Sprint/*
    - Unity/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -Ei.bak '/ +- develop/{p;s/[a-z]+/TerraformTest\/*/}' file
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - TerraformTest/*
      - release/*
      - rapid/*
      - Sprint/*
      - Unity/*
```